# How to extract value of <td> using jsoup ?

Tags: jsoup

I have an HTML which is generated by the tool so i have no control over it. When i try to extract values from the html using jsoup, i am facing challenges to identify the element as they have not defined ids to it.

```
<table width="45%" border="0">
<tr bgcolor="#666666">
<td width="45%" height="24"><strong><font color="#FFFFFF" size="2"    face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Risk Level</font></strong></td><td width="55%" align="center"><strong><font color="#FFFFFF" size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Defects</font></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#e8e8e8">
<td><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><a href="#first">First</a></font></td><td align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">0</font></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#e8e8e8">
<td><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><a href="#second">Second</a></font></td><td align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">5</font></td>
```

I would need to find the value of td tags following the td tag with Value First ( which is 0, i will need to find it) and Second (which is 5, again needs to be found).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // SET the URL
        String url = "http://localhost/parser.html";

        try {
            // Obtain the HTML
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

            // Get font tag in every second td tag
            Elements tdsFont = doc.select("td:nth-child(2n) > font");

            for (Element element : tdsFont) {
                System.out.println(element.text());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```